# Update Magento index for one or more specific products

Tags: magento

I want to know if there is a way to update a magento index for one or more products.  So for example, I have 100 products that I have just programmatically updated the price... and now I need to kick of the indexer so that it reindexes the price for those 100 products.  So just for clarity...

I know that it is possible simply refresh one index on ALL products.  For example, this will refresh the pricing index on all products:

```
$process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
$process->reindexEverything();
```

And I also know it is possible to refresh ALL the indexes on just one product (or several products if you do this in a loop):

```
Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction(
  $product, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 
  Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE
);
```

*BUT, neither of these options work for me.*  I need to be able to do the cross section of these two.  How can I take one or more products, and refresh just one index, such as the price index?

I am working with Magento CE 1.6.2.0.

**EDIT:** By the way, on Magento 1.3 I was able to accomplish this by doing the following, but this doesn't seem to work anymore.

```
Mage::getModel('catalogindex/indexer')->plainReindex(
  $listOfProductIds,
  Mage_CatalogIndex_Model_Indexer::REINDEX_TYPE_PRICE
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalogindex/indexer')->plainReindex($productIds);
Mage::getSingleton('catalogindex/aggregation')->clearProductData($productIds);
```

Another idea:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_indexer_price')->reindexProductIds($productIds);
```

This one works for me:

```
$catalogSearchIndexer = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalogsearch/fulltext');
$catalogSearchIndexer->rebuildIndex($storeId, $productIds);
```

Comment: Hi Zyava.  Are you sure that works on Magento 1.6?  That is basically the same code that we have working on a Magento 1.3 installation, but doesn't seem to work on 1.6.  I could be doing something wrong, but I thought I would ask if you have successfully gotten this to work on 1.6?

Comment: It should work because I found this code in `app\code\core\Mage\CatalogIndex\Model\Observer.php`, see method `processAfterSaveEvent()`. Are you sure you select admin store in your script (`Mage::app('admin')`)?

Comment: Thanks doing a code search, but I am absolutely certain that it doesn't work, at least not on magento ce 1.6.2.0. It did work back on 1.3.3.0. That section of the code was essentially depricated (even though there are no notes saying so) - just search for references to that method in the code base and you will see that it isn't ever called. I think what happened is the Mage_CatalogIndex module was replaced by the Mage_Index module.

Comment: Seems like you are right. I updated my answer with another idea.

Comment: Thanks for the try Zyava, but is appears that the updated answer doesn't work on Magento CE 1.6.2.0 either.  The Mage_CatalogIndex module seems to be related to the catalogindex_* tables, which I don't think are used anymore.  The newer Mage_Index module updates are associated with the catalog_product_index* tables (and a few others), and it looks like the catalog pages look at tables like catalog_product_index_price to find pricing info (as opposed to looking at catalogindex_price and catalogindex_minimal_price like it used to in v 1.3).

Answer (score 1):

If you have your Index Mode set to manual, it still keeps track over all changes in index_event. You can index all the pending changes with `$process->indexEvents();`

Comment: Does this method change index status to "Ready"? After running this method, index management still shows "index required" as status.